# Exception Handling

Tags: c#, .net

how we can return some value in `try-catch` for example

```
try
{
  return abc;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
console.Writeline("Exception occur" + ex);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Not sure what your asking here are you getting a not all code paths return a value error

Comment: Umm, by using `return`?! Provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will return 2 (exception occured) if you call the method.

```
int testException()
{

    try
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        return a / b;
        //return 1;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`Try Catch` is a way of handling errors in your code that cause you to need to leave the normal flow of the program.  Many .net system components throw errors to indicate a condition that is not expected any code can be put in a catch block;

```
object x;
try
{
   x = Func();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   //Set some default Value
   x = new Object();
   //Send an email error 
   SendErrorMail();
}
return x;
```

If you just need to return inside of a catch you can use a return statement just like you would anywhere else in your code.

Comment: sorry if my statement is confusing you actually i want to return some values in try cage.

Comment: you can just use return.  Its valid anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
try 
   { 
        return abc; 
   } 
catch(Exception ex) 
   { 
        console.Writeline("Exception occur" + ex); 
        return some_value;
   }
```

Comment: Returning an error code from a `catch` block somewhat defeats the purpose of exceptions.